# Any way to detect Force Click with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, browser, click, pressure.js

Is there any way to detect a Force Click with Javascript? I know there are ways to detect regular and right clicks, but what about Force Clicks?

Comment: There is nothing like force detection for mouse clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the `webkitmouseforcewillbegin` and `webkitmouseforcedown` events. You can get the force level from the `webkitForce` property in the object passed into the event handler.

Of course, this only works on Safari on Macs with Force Touch support.

Source: [WebKit DOM Programming Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/RespondingtoForceTouchEventsfromJavaScript.html)

Answer (score 6):

I've found a JS library called [Pressure.js](http://pressurejs.com/) that makes handling Force/3D Touch simpler. It works for both iOS with 3D touch and OSX with force touch. If you are using it for just force touch on Mac, you could use it like this:

```
Pressure.set('#element', {
  start: function(event){
    // this is called on force start
  },
  end: function(){
    // this is called on force end
  },
  startDeepPress: function(event){
    // this is called on "force click" / "deep press", aka once the force is greater than 0.5
  },
  endDeepPress: function(){
    // this is called when the "force click" / "deep press" end
  },
  change: function(force, event){
    // this is called every time there is a change in pressure
  },
  unsupported: function(){
    // this is called once there is a touch on the element and the device or browser does not support Force or 3D touch
  }
}, {only: 'force'});
```

The `{only: 'force'}` options at the end make sure it only runs for force touch on Mac and not also on iOS. If you want it to run on both simple remove that option.